# yii active record relations

Tags: php, mysql, yii, orm

I have 2 tables, categories(id, name) and products(id, categoryId, title, content) and my models look like this

```
class Category extends CActiveRecord {
    public $id;
    public $name;
    public function tableName() { return 'categories'; }
    public function relations() {
        return array('products' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Product', 'categoryId'));
    }
}
class Product extends CActiveRecord {
    public $id;
    public $title;
    public $content;
    public function tableName() { return 'products'; }
}
```

The problem is when I try to access the products like this

```
Category::model()->with('products')->findAll()
```

> The relation "products" in active record class "Category" is specified with an invalid foreign key "categoryId". There is no such column in the table "categories".

I looked at the documentation with the User / Post example and don't understand why my example is not working. Can someone clear things up please? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that product table has field called `categoryId` in order to save the primary key of `category` table

Comment: My products table has a categoryId column.

Comment: @CipQuestion: Then why it is not in `Products` model ?

Comment: I tried adding it to the model and still nothing, the same error.

Comment: how did you created the model ? using `gii` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try specifing `categoryid` instead of `categoryId`. The reason can be in `lower_case_table_names` mysql directive.